# subforms in Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

How subforms created in zend?
Please explain with an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [chapter on Subforms in the ZF Reference Guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.forms.html#zend.form.forms.subforms):

```
$subForm = new Zend_Form_SubForm;
$subForm->addElements(
     // element configurations
);

$mainForm = new Zend_Form;
$mainForm->addSubForm($subForm, 'subformName');
```

Also see http://devzone.zend.com/search/results?q=zend+form